# Set file permission not public with django-storages and S3boto

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm developing django1.4 application with django-storages and botoS3.

I have model like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='my_image')
```

I don't want to the image public, but django-storage set the file permission public
(Grantee : Everyone Open/Download) automatically.

Could you tell me how to set permission not public automatically?
Thanks!

Comment: django-storages should set the ACL for the key according to the bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` setting, if you set it to `'private'`, s3boto will store the files as private.

I think this is not documented, but you can see a complete list of django-storage S3 parameters in the [source code of the original `__init__` function](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/src/83fa2f0ba20c/storages/backends/s3boto.py#cl-121).